# How does this work? About saving strings in array

Tags: c

I am trying to read a series of names from a text file and save them into an array. 
Everything looked okay until I try to reference a specific name by using indexes (ex: array[0] ). It gives me t25.txt where it should of give me t1.txt. What did I do wrong?

Here's what I have:

```
#define MAX_STRING 25

FILE *in;

in = fopen("filenames.txt", "r");
if (!in) {
    printf("Failed to open the file\n");
    exit(1);
}

char array[MAX_STRING]; 
// In my mind, I want it to look like this:
// array[0] = t1.txt
// array[1] = t2.txt
int i;

for ( i = 0; i < MAX_STRING; i++ ) // Get 25 words
{
    fscanf( in, "%s", array);
    printf( "filename = %s\n", array); 
    // I print it out to make sure it's getting what i want and it did
}
```

My text file - filenames.txt is something like this 
t1.txt 
t2.txt

Thanks much

Comment: array[0] = 't' in your comment but not the entire string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char array[MAX_STRING];
```

is an array of characters, not an array of strings. Your loop overwrites this array in every iteration. You might have meant something like

```
char array[N_STRINGS][MAX_LENGTH_OF_A_SINGLE_STRING];
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't saving multiple strings in one array, you are overwriting one string multiple times.

In C each string is saved as an array, so you have to have something like a 2D-Array: Dimension 1: the String, Dimension 2: The "array":

```
array[MAX_STRING][MAX_NAME_LEN]
```

This is what you intend to do!

You have to understand C-Strings as an Array of Characters in continous memmory, with a \0 at the end to identify the end of the "string". You are handling with arrays when you are handling with strings!

Answer (score 1):

you define `char array[MAX_STRING];` which simply defines one string

so

```
array[0] = 't'
array[1] = 'x'
```

What you need is `char array[NUM_STRING][MAX_STRING]`